# Why isn't my trim function working?

Tags: javascript, trim

I'm supposed to create a trim function for my javascript class. I thought I had everything right, but for some reason it won't work. Can someone check my code to see what I'm missing or how to make it work?

```
window.onload=function()
{
    window.alert(trim("           test")); 
};

function trim(data)
{
    var result;
    var whitespace;
    var start;
    whitespace="\n\r\t\f";
    start=0;

 if(typeof data === "string")
    {

    while(start<data.length, data.charAt(start)===whitespace)
    {
        start=start+1;
    }                      //end loop scope

    var end;
    end=data.length-1;

    while(end>=0, data.charAt(end)===whitespace)
    {
        end=end-1;
    }                      //end loop scope

    if(end<start)
    {
        result="";
    }

    else

    {
        result=data.substring(start, end+1);
    }
}

else             //else for first if statement

{
    return result;
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: I doubt a single character is going to equal `\n\r\t\f` Also where is a whitespace character?

Comment: Please elaborate on the "it won't work" part. What doesn't work? What is the result you get and what do you expect instead?

Comment: My assignment sheet told me to set whitespace to "\n\r\t\f". The whitespace is the spaces before the word "     test"

Comment: When I preform the function, I get a result of "        test" and I would like to get a result of "test"

Answer (score 0):

You should use `\s` to match whitespace. I've also simplified the function for you.

```js
function trim(data) {
  
  if(typeof data === "string") {
    return data.replace(/(^[\s\r\n\t\f]+|[\s\r\n\t\f]+$)/g, '');
  }
  return data;
}

var result = trim('             test              ');
document.write(result);
document.write('<br>Length of string: '+result.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function trim(string)
{
    return string.trim();
}
```

:-)

Comment: Not enough jQuery. You should totally use [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) for extra points.